# Changing colors from specific parts of a bitmap image

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

I am writing an Android application that must paint determined parts of a loaded bitmap image according to received events.

I need to paint (or change the current color) of a single part of a bitmap image, without changing the rest of the image.

Let's say I have a car, which is divided by many parts: door, windows, wheels, etc.
Each time an event (received from the network) arrives, I need to change the color of that particular part with the color specified by the event data.
What would be the best technique to achieve that?

I first thought on FloodFill, as suggested on many threads in SO, but given that the messages are received quite fast (several per second) I fear it would drag performance down, as it seem to be very CPU intensive algorithm.

I also thought about having multiple segments of the same image, each colored with a different color and show the right one at the right time, but the car has at least 10 different parts and each one could be painted with 4-6 colors, so I would end up with dozens of images and that would be impractical to handle, not to mention the waste of memory.

So, is there any other approach?

Comment: You can't have it both ways--if you want blinding speed, they should be pre-rendered. I don't see any real issue with that. Without knowing much about the actual "part" definitions etc. it's difficult to provide meaningful speed comparisons.

Comment: The parts themselves are not complex - it is a stylized drawing - and I believe they would draw quickly. It's the number of parts x colors combinations that worries me. I have also thought on having separate transparent images for each part, painting them with the appropriate color and drawing over the existing complete image, but have no idea how to precisely position at the right coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest  way to do it is with a shader. You'll need to use OpenGL ES 2 for that (some Androids only support ES 1). You'll need a temporary bitmap the same size as the image you want to change. Set it as the target. In the shader, retrieve a pixel from the sampler which is bound to the image you want to change. If it's within a small tolerance of the colour you want to change, set gl_FragColor to the new colour, otherwise just set gl_FragColor to the colour you retrieved from the sampler. You'll need to pass the desired colour and the new colour into the shader as vec4s with `al_set_shader_float_vector`. The fastest way to do this is to keep 2 bitmaps and swap between them as the "main one" that you're using each time a colour changes.

If you can't use a shader, then you'll have to lock the bitmap and replace the colour. Use `al_lock_bitmap` to lock it, then you can use `al_get_pixel` and `al_put_pixel` to change colours. Then `al_unlock_bitmap` when you're done. You can also avoid using al_get_pixel/al_put_pixel and access the memory manually which will be faster. If you lock the bitmap with the format `ALLEGRO_PIXEL_FORMAT_ABGR_8888_LE` then the memory is laid out like so:

`int w = al_get_bitmap_width(bitmap);
    int h = al_get_bitmap_height(bitmap);
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        unsigned char *p = locked_region->data + locked_region->pitch * y;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            unsigned char r = p[0];
            unsigned char g = p[1];
            unsigned char b = p[2];
            unsigned char a = p[3];
            /* change r, g, b, a here if they match */
            p[0] = r;
            p[1] = g;
            p[2] = b;
            p[3] = a;
            p += 4;
        }
    }`

It's recommended that you lock the image in the format it was created in. That means pick an easy one like the one I mentioned, or else the inner part of the loop gets more complicated. The ABGR_8888 part of the pixel format describes the layout of the data. ABGR tells the order of the components. If you were to read a pixel into a single storage unit (an int in this case but it works the same with a short) then the bit pattern would be `AAAAAAAABBBBBBBBGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRR`. However, when you're reading a byte at a time, most machine are little endian so that means the small end comes first. That's why in my sample code p[0] is red. The 8888 part tells how many bits per component.